# Need assistance positioning icon to the right of my text

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

I am having difficulties aligning the icon to the right of the quantity. When I try float:right it positions the icon to the very right of the cell rather than up against the text. Is there a way to get it to the right of the text but right up against it? Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
            <div>
                <th class="fd-table--header-cell" [innerHTML]="quantity | fdContent"></th>
                <div class="myclass">
                    <a [attr.id]="mySelector"
                        [attr.aria-describedby]="myTooltip" href="javascript:void(0);"
                        class="fd-tooltip-layer--selector">

                        <help-icon [helpIconId]="myHelpIconId" [content]="pageDataContent"
                            aria-label="icon" [title]="quantity"></help-icon>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>


.myclass {
float: right;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), and add `display:flex` to parent of both the HTML elment.

make parent element as `flexbox container` and its direct children will be treated as `flex elements`. Flexbox by default direction i.e `flex-direction` is `row`, So it will make `flex elements` align `left to right`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <strong>quantity</strong>
  <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using Flexbox. Try the following:

Create a class:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Add it to the parent div:

```
<div class="container">
   <th class="fd-table--header-cell" [innerHTML]="quantity | fdContent"></th>
   <div class="myclass">
      <a [attr.id]="mySelector"
      [attr.aria-describedby]="myTooltip" href="javascript:void(0);"
      class="fd-tooltip-layer--selector">
      <help-icon [helpIconId]="myHelpIconId" [content]="pageDataContent"
      aria-label="icon" [title]="quantity"></help-icon>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Add appropriate spacing:

```
.myclass {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```